# mysql COUNT results with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table with with 2 unique linked table ids.
I get the results I want with GROUP BY but when I count I only get the number of each group.

When I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table GROUP BY first_linked_table_id, second_linked_table_id
```

I get as results 1, 2, 3, 1 but I want 4 as a result.

I tried DISTINCT but I think that only works with one column

Comment: No, `DISTINCT` works with any number of columns, but it won't change much as `DISTINCT` is usually implemented by `GROUP BY` under the hood.  Please include some sample data here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen DISTINCT only returns the unique values of one specific column, what I want is every row where the combination first_linked_table_id and second_linked_table_id is unique

Comment: No, you're wrong.  You can use `DISTINCT field1, field2`, but in any case this is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I know DISTINCT field1, field 2 is possible but it's not what I'm looking for. That returns 1, 1 and 2, 1 where I also want 1, 2 and 1, 3

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your requirement is to get count of number of groups. So we need two operations-

> 1. Group(inner query)
> 2. Count(outer query)

Following query will do precisely that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(id) 
    FROM my_table 
    GROUP BY first_linked_table_id,
             second_linked_table_id
) t
```

Comment: it returns the error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: sorry, I tried using an enter submitting my comment when it wasnt ready. I edited it

Comment: _Try This_ answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers about how your solution works and why it is a good solution.  Please take a moment to explain your answer so that it is more valuable to readers and role models better posting behavior to new users.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to count the rows, I think you're going to need a subquery. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table GROUP BY first_linked_table_id, second_linked_table_id
);
```